# Getting dates in PHP is a good way or any other methods for this?

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
echo date("d-m-Y"); // Today

$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));  // tomorrow
echo date('d-m-Y',$tomorrow);

$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"));  //  lastmonth
echo date('d-m-Y',$lastmonth);

$nextyear  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d"),   date("Y")+1);  //  nextyear
echo date('d-m-Y',$nextyear);

$afterAweek  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+7, date("Y"));  // after a week
echo date('d-m-Y',$afterAweek);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why did you tag this with codeigniter? This has nothing to do with codeigniter.  You didn't ask a question - how do you think we can answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use mktime. strtotime is more human friendly

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("now"));
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 day"));
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-1 month"));
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 year"));
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week"));
```

not needed, but useful, too

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("last Monday"));
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("next Monday"));
```

Comment: Thanks you very much sir.